# Potentiometer with No Minimum Resistance

Tags: current, voltage-regulator, resistance, potentiometer, linear-regulator

I'm looking to create a variable current regulator with the LM317 using 1-turn pots.
I know that I am going to need to have a resistance of 1.25 Ohms to have a current of 1A, which I want to be my max; however, all of the pots that I have (barring trimpots) have a resistance of around 1.8 ohms when at their minimum setting, and I want to use 2 in series (for fine and coarse adjustment) which would bring total resistance to 3.6 ohms. Is there any way to get around this?

Thanks,
Michael

Comment: Hmm, I don't believe your 1.8 ohm number.  Most of that (I'm guessing) is in the DMM.  To measure low resistances use some current source.. it could be a voltage source and large resistance, and then measure the voltage drop.  I'm guessing (again) you'll want to add some small resistance to the wiper of your pot.

Answer (score 3):

Do not put 1A through the wiper on the pot. Put a resistor in series with the output, pot element in parallel, and tap the adj voltage from the wiper. The pot resistance is not critical- 1K would work fine.

Answer (score -2):

You can put a resistor is parallel.